# error C2988 - template declarations in C++ when converting from VC6 to VS 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, visual-c++, migration

I want to migrate a Visual Studio 6.0 C++ projects that was developed in the last century to Visual Studio 2015, which includes some third party libs, one of them making extensive use of template definitions. One of the templates looks like this:

```
template <class TL> void RWTIsvDlist<TL>::apply(void (*applyFun)(TL*, void*), void* p)
{
    //...
}
```

This leads to a compiler error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/dewfinition, and a lot of subsequent errors.

Generally, I would like to know what is exactly causing this error, and what is missing in that specific template declaration.

Comment: On which line the error happens, i mean it doesn't happens on the line of template definition, instead it happens where you use it.

Comment: @Yola: Actually, template functions _should_ be compiled twice. Once when defined, once when instantiated. I say _should_ because it's a long-standing VC++ bug.

Comment: Just checking, but `template <class TL> class RWTIsvDlist { ... }` itself has been defined prior? All compilers will be confused if you try to define a class method before defining the class itself.

Comment: @MSalters thanks, i forget about this all the time:)